# Move a file from the current users desktop?

Tags: vb.net

I was making a installer for some program I made, and I was wondering if I could copy the folder with the contents from the Current Users desktop to another area, how would I do so?Im using: `My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile("", "")`

Move the folder "Emailer" (on the desktop) to System files (x86)

Comment: Worth noting that you need to be elevated to move into the system files folder in Win7+...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To acces path to the desktop use:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
```

Comment: As @George wrote: File.Move(path, path2);. I do not know what folder you would like to move, if you update your question I can write more

Answer (score 0):

After you've obtained the desktop location (as Garath has pointed out in his answer), check out *File.Move* in the System.IO namespace. e.g

```
File.Move(path, path2);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx